# How much does Xdebug profiling inflate the real execution time?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I have an Xdebug cachegrind file in webgrind showing that `1061 different functions were called in 5865 milliseconds` - when I disable profiling the script doesn't take that many milliseconds - I realize I could work this out but does anyone know the approximate percentage increase in execution time caused by Xdebug profiling?

Thanks

Comment: I am woundering the same thing thinking about using it for an app but really want to know what it will do the the perofmance i am thinking it does not store its self in ram to not effect the php so it will end up using a lot of disk io i recommend you use tmpfs or something on your linux to try to keep it from writing to disk all the time and than maybe a cron job or something to input it into a database or something

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to say a specific number or percentage since that depends in the type and quantity of function calls, variables used and options you set in your xdebug.ini.

Here you can check a bit of research and tests done by some people.
[short information about xdebug and the lexer cals](http://nikic.github.com/2012/01/19/Careful-XDebug-can-skew-your-performance-numbers.html)

[xdebug support mailing list](http://search.gmane.org/?query=overhead&group=gmane.comp.php.xdebug.general)

But of course, the final answer is yours, your application, your coding standards and your configurations are the ones that will set the final overhead.

Just remember, that as a general rule, xdebug should not be active in a production server. Some people have it enabled and everything is ok, but it's usually not a good idea.

Bye