# Does PHP's xdebug and qcachegrind record/report on time spent waiting for a database?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

Using PHP 5.5 on Amazon GNU/Linux.

Xdebug is recording profile data from a PHP app running via apache worker MPM.

When I view profile data with qcachegrind (running on an OS X laptop), very little time is attributed to php::mysql_* functions.

I know that this application is spending a substantial percentage of its time running database queries.

Is Xdebug not recording time spent waiting for the database or I am maybe not using qcachegrind correctly to view time spent waiting within the total time spent running PHP built in functions?

Comment: Try doing a query with a short run time and another query that returns the same result but has a long run time, then look at the profile data.  That should show if that gets recorded.  It's also worth bearing in mind that application benchmarking/profiling and database benchmarking/profiling are distinct activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, running `mysql_query('SELECT SLEEP(5)')` results in a ~5000ms self-cost for the `php::mysql_query` function, so yes - it should report time spent waiting for the database.

Keep in mind though, using the xdebug profiler adds a lot of overhead to running PHP, so the proportion of time reportedly spent waiting for the database may not be the same as when running without the profiler (because the profiling of PHP doesn't add any overhead to the database engine itself).

Comment: Any idea how much is the 'typical' xdebug overhead (if there is such a thing as 'typical' overhead)?

Comment: You'll have to test your application with and without it (and measure total response times) to know for sure, but you'll never find out how much it adds to each DB query. EDIT: See [these](http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/19/Careful-XDebug-can-skew-your-performance-numbers.html) great [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168426/how-much-does-xdebug-profiling-inflate-the-real-execution-time) for more information.